# One HTTPS ajax call in codeigniter

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, codeigniter, https

I am trying to create a secure login for my site, who's form logs in with AJAX.  Unfortunately, as it currently stands, I am sending the username and password using http completely unencrypted.  After looking through basic encryption methods in Javascript that I can port to Codeigniter to decrypt, I've read that the best thing to do is just use HTTPS to send the data.  So basically what I want to do is this:

1. Someone fills out their credentials on my site.
2. The data gets ajaxed to https//:MY-SITE.com/ajax/login
3. It responds as normal.

Unfortunately, when I set this up, my AJAX function that had been working when using http stopped sending the response it was supposed to send.  Do I need to do something extra to get my AJAX function properly read with codeigniter using HTTPS?

Comment: For the record; most logins send both username and password unencrypted. Those that don't use HTTPS, that is.

Comment: Is that not dangerous?  Like a packet sniffer could pick that up pretty easily i'd think.

Comment: Don't know if this is a good idea - but what if you did like a javascript md5 function on the username and password and used those hashes in your application? Would this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't request information between HTTP and HTTPS using AJAX due to cross-domain issues. To get this to work, consider implementing JSONP as part of your login script. This way, you can perform the login between domains.

jQuery has a great JSONP implementation; it's worth checking out if you're not using it already.